# Recursive neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph which has categories and sub-categories and sub-sub-categories to indefinite level.
How I can I get all this hierarchical data in one cipher query?

I currently have this query :

```
START category=node:categoryNameIndex(categoryName = "category") 
MATCH path = category <-        [rel:parentCategory] - subcategory 
RETURN category, collect(subcategory);
```

Which gives me following result:

```
| category                                                                                               | collect(subcategory)                                                                                                                                                                                           |
==> +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[26]{categoryName:"Test2",categoryDescription:"testDesc",imageUrl:"testUrl",imageName:"imageName"} | [Node[25]{categoryName:"Test1",categoryDescription:"testDesc",imageUrl:"testUrl",imageName:"imageName"}]                                                                                                       |
==> | Node[1]{categoryName:"Test1",categoryDescription:"testDesc",imageUrl:"testUrl",imageName:"imageName"}  | [Node[26]{categoryName:"Test2",categoryDescription:"testDesc",imageUrl:"testUrl",imageName:"imageName"},Node[2]{categoryName:"Test2",categoryDescription:"testDesc",imageUrl:"testUrl",imageName:"imageName"}] |
```

I am using node-neo4j.
I will give an example of what I want in json format.

```
[{
    "categoryName": "Test2",
    "categoryDescription": "testDesc",
    "imageUrl": "testUrl",
    "children": [{
        "categoryName": "Test1",
        "categoryDescription": "testDesc",
        "imageUrl": "testUrl",
        "children" :  [{
            "categoryName": "Test1",
            "categoryDescription": "testDesc",
            "imageUrl": "testUrl"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I this possible? I know I can always do it programmatically OR by using multiple queries. But it will very helpful if it can be done in a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match paths of arbitrary depth by adding a `*` after the relationship type:

```
START category=node:categoryNameIndex(categoryName = "category") 
MATCH path = category <-[rel:parentCategory*]- subcategory 
RETURN category, collect(subcategory);
```

Optionally, you can also specify a minimum and/or maximum path length:

```
START category=node:categoryNameIndex(categoryName = "category") 
MATCH path = category <-[rel:parentCategory*2..5]- subcategory 
RETURN category, collect(subcategory);
```

See reference here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-match.html#match-variable-length-relationships

Comment: Thank you @ean5533. I will elaborate my question for better understanding.

Comment: Does this answer not answer your question? It is a single query.

Comment: No it does answer my question. If you check JSON example that I have given, I want it in a _hierarchical format_. I am currently doing this be firing multiple queries. I don't know whether this is even possible, but if it then that will be very helpful.

Comment: It seems there is no way doing what I want in a single query. I just wanted to avoid firing multiple queries. But first query from your answer was useful, thanks for that.